# Can i have different return type in kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, return-type

For example let's say I call a function like this:

```
val call1: String = myFunction()
```

or

```
val call2: Int = myFunction()
```

How can I let my function decide what to return in fonction of the call and not the function itself ? What should be the return type ? Any ? Unit ?  ?

I don't know if it's clear so here the example on what I'm working on:

I have this line:

```
var query: Query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(path)
```

Here we will get a Query but if I do that:

```
var query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(path)
```

I'll get a databaseReference

So i'm trying to get either a query or a databaseReference according to the call of the function and not the function.

Comment: databaseReference is a Query - you are not deciding anything- its just databaseReference can be cast to Query which you do in the first call

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of fake it. In java it's already feasible to write a method like this:

```
public <T> T foo(Class<T> clazz) { /* Do stuff */ }
```

That returns different things based on the class you pass in.

You'll likely still want to have something like that to do the heavy lifting, but you can make the interface to it a bit nicer:

```
interface Interface {}
class Clazz() : Interface {}
class Clbzz() : Interface {}
fun <T: Interface> foo(clazz: KClass<T>) : T { /* return a T */ }
inline fun <reified T: Interface> foo() : T { return foo(T::class) }

val a =  foo<Clazz>()
val b : Clbzz = foo()
```